# HornetQ MessageHandler howto

Tags: transactions, hornetq, core-api

I have a bit of understanding problems using hornetQ. What I am trying to realize is asynchronous request processing. I have a server component accepting incoming tcp connections. The clients will send requests in a proprietary protocol using TLV messages. To decouple the processing from the io stuff I introduced a message queue using hornetQ. So when a new message comes in it is just put into an INBOX queue. There are several listeners threads to that queue  so processing is multi-threaded. These listeners will produce responses in turn and put them back into OUTBOX queue. Every client has its own outbox queue so they won't influence each other (e.g. when a client has temporarily disconnected).
So for the outbox handling I create a ClientProducer and set the MessageHandler property to get notified in case a message is put into the outbox queue.

So far I am clear. But now the problem is, when the targeted client is not connected I cannot send the message right away but have to invite him to connect again (unidirectional communication). But what to do with the message in that case? I don't use transaction handling so I cannot rollback to put the message back into the queue. Maybe a code snippet can make more clear what I am trying to do:

```
@Override
public void onMessage(ClientMessage p_message)
{
    try
    {
        UID uid = UID.parse(p_message.getStringProperty(MessageQueueServer.MESSAGE_PROPERTY_UID));
        IoSession ioSession = SessionLookupFilter.getSession(uid);

        if ((ioSession != null) && ioSession.isConnected())
        {
            ioSession.write(MessageQueueServer.clientMessageToLTV(p_message));
            // acknowledge to remove message from queue
            p_message.acknowledge();
        }
        else
        {
            // don't acknowledge the message so we will get it again ?!?
            // TODO invite the client to establish a connection via SIP server
            // Set redelivery timeout of message to a serious value so we don't bother the client with subsequent
            // invitations.
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        LogMF.error(log, e, "Error during dispatching of mq-message {0} to client.", new Object[] { p_message });
    }
}
```

I could not get something useful from the hornetq user-manual. SO maybe someone has experience with that.

Greets Sebastian